# C++ design: subclass, or are there better ways?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a `Cheese` class. In my program, I deal a lot with collection of cheeses, mostly `vector<Cheese>` objects.

I want to be able to `eat()` a cheese collection, something like this:

```
vector<Cheese> cheeses;
//cheeses = ...
cheeses.eat();
```

How to do this? How do I add a new member function to the `vector<Cheese>` class? Should I just subclass the `vector<Cheese>` class, name the subclass `CheeseCollection` and add the member function there, or are there any better ways?

Coming from Objective-C, I'm used to categories, which allowed me to add functions ("methods") to classes. Is something like that available in C++, or is it considered more natural to subclass like crazy in C++?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't subclass `std::vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ you simply wouldn’t use a member function for this – use a free function:

```
void eat(std::vector<Cheese> const& cheeses) {
    // …
}
```

This is a close equivalent to those Obj-C categories even though the syntax differs (and you’re not using member access).

The standard library container classes weren’t designed to be subclassable so that approach will fail. What you could do is use composition instead of inheritance – i.e. have a `CheeseCollection` class which contains a vector of cheeses as a member. This may have some advantages, depending on your overall design. However, in general the above is the most C++ic solution.

Comment: It should be "C++-esque". (JK, +1.)

Comment: But where would I put this function? In what file? What would I name the file? What is the convention for "free utility functions" like these? Should the function be declared in a `.h` file and defined in a `.cpp` file, just like we do for classes?

Comment: Place it in the header/source it is most related to. That might be `Cheese.h`. And yes, declare it in the header and define it in the implementation file (unless of course you want it inlined or it's a function template).

Comment: @H2CO3 I was thinking about an appropriate word but I like my variant because (1) it doesn’t use a (visually somewhat redundant) “-” and (2) it’s a contraction (portmanteau) of “C++” and “idiomatic”. How about “C++tic” as a compromise? ;-)

Comment: @DennisRitchie Same as for member functions: declare in header and define in `.cpp` file. The function should be logically grouped (and put into a namespace) with other functions which pertain to managing a cheese collection.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. One more question though: "The standard library container classes weren’t designed to be subclassable so that approach will fail." Why? Not that I'm going to do it, but what would go wrong if I would just subclass `vector<Cheese>`?

Comment: @DennisRitchie: The standard collections don't have virtual destructors, so (public) inheritance from them can be dangerous -- if you destroy one via a pointer/reference to the base class, it won't be destroyed correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Neither -- what you want is an algorithm. Assuming you have an `eat` that already knows how to eat one Cheese object, applying it to an entire collection would be something like:

```
std::for_each(cheeses.begin(), cheeses.end(), eat).
```

Unlike some other languages, C++ does not maintain a slavish adherence to object orientation, even when it makes no real sense.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind for these "loop through each object" cases. +1. However, imagine that I have some other function where I'm just acting on the collection as a whole. I suppose I chose a bad example :)

Comment: @DennisRitchie: C++ has a fair number of algorithms for acting on collections as a whole, and they can be surprisingly versatile.

Comment: @Dennis the collection already has its member functions. collections do not eat. if there is a class that eats - composition as shown above. if there is no membership for the collection and there are several interested classes that want the collection to be eaten (passive!) then freestanding algorithms are the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is define your own class which uses (encapsulates) the vector:

```
class Cheeses
{
  vector<Cheese> v;
public:
  void eat()
  {
    v.erase();
  }

  // plus other methods which delegate to the contained vector
};
```